# Override base class method and extending literal type return

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, overriding, return-type

Consider the follow snippet. A class with single variable and a pair of accessors.

```js
export class Base {
  private _var: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'foo';

  get var(): 'foo' | 'bar' {
    return this._var;
  }
  set var(value: 'foo' | 'bar') {
    this._var = value;
  }
}
```

If I want to extend `Base` class and override `var()` in the meantime return a more specific type by extending it from `'foo' | 'bar'`, is it possible to do that?

If I do this I will get error TS2416

```js
export class Derived extends Base {
  override get var(): 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz' {
    // TODO
  }
  override set var(value: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz') {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

```
error TS2416: Property 'var' in type 'Derived' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Base'.
  Type '"foo" | "bar" | "baz"' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar"'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use generic types

```js
export class Base<T = 'foo' | 'bar'> {
  protected _var:T = 'foo';

  get var(): T {
    return this._var;
  }
  set var(value: T) {
    this._var = value;
  }
}

export class Sub<T = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'> extends Base<T> {
  
}
```

Alternatively you can `override` the getter (but not the setter as the Base uses `private` for `_var`). You will have to use `any` as the return type though

```js
class Sub extends Base {
    override get var(): any {
        return 'test';
    }
}

const sub = new Sub();
console.log(sub.var)
```

I can't think of any other options myself - especially as you mentioned in the comment you don't have access to `Base` class

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have no access to the base class source code, is it I am running out of option?